# Necesito hacer un util de find and replace en java

Tags: java, str-replace

Necesito ayuda con un `util` de java.

En el programa que estoy haciendo necesito una utilidad de `find and replace`.

Necesito que funcione con documentos de texto y de excel.

No puedo usar las herramientas de programas como `notepad` o el mismo `excel` para hacer el `find and replace`. Ya que me piden que sea automatico, es para una aplicacion web de cargas a base de datos y algunos de los archivos de datos nos llegan con datos que necesitan ser reemplazados.

De momento tengo esto

```
static void modifyFile(String filePath, String oldString, String newString){

    File fileToBeModified = new File(filePath);
    String oldContent = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    FileWriter writer = null;

    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToBeModified)); 
        //Lectura de todas las líneas del archivo
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) 
        {
            oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        //Reemplazo el contenido viejo
        String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
        //Reescrivo el fichero
        writer = new FileWriter(fileToBeModified);
        writer.write(newContent);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    modifyFile("file.txt", ".", "0");
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

Me reemplaza el archivo, pero no los puntos, si no todo entero por 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que usas [`replaceAll`](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:String.replaceAll()).

El primer parámetro es un string que representa una [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) y punto significa cualquier caracter.

Tienes que escapar el caracter punto con  `\\.` tal que `modifyFile("file.txt", "\\.", "0");`